# Xcode 4.6.1 debugger local variables not available

Tags: debugging, xcode4.6

I recently upgraded Xcode 4.6 to 4.6.1, and I notice the following abnormal behaviour:

1. Sometimes, Local Variables are not available upon a breakpoint
2. Upon Step Into and Step Over when being suspended over a breakpoint, the editor highlights the incorrect line the code.

The LLVM 4.2 Compiler - COde Generation / Optimization level is set to None for Debug. I have tried cleaning the project, the simulator, etc. No luck.

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that in my Run Configuration, I had chosen *Release* instead of *Debug*. Perhaps for Release, the compiler does some code optimisation, because of which, the compiled code and the source code get out of synch.

Attached is where I had made a mistake:

[image]

Comment: Great, worked for me. In my case, i was using a custom scheme called mock (uses mock data). Does anyone know if we can turn on debugging of local variables for build configurations other than Debug?

Answer (score 1):

It may also happen if you enable options like address Sanitizer in "Scheme > RUN > Diagnostics"

[image: Diagnostics]

Comment: This is a correct answer. Tested on XCode 10.2.1 Wifi debug iPhoneX.